# Is there a way to establish an angle distribution coordinates with Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

Can I use Mathematica to plot an angle distribution like the images shown below, where the angle stands for an axis and the length along the radius stands for another axis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  It would help if you gave a short example of the data (or function) you would like to plot in a way that could be pasted into Mathematica.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `PolarPlot` and `ListPolarPlot`? But the "axes" descriptions would have to be done by hand (e.g. with `Graphics`-language).

Answer (score 4):

Lots of such stuff can be done with little effort manually. For example, this draws everything explicitly:

```
With[{maxr = 90}, 
 Graphics[{Table[
    With[{v = {Cos[a Degree], Sin[a Degree]}}, {{LightGray, 
       Line[maxr {{0, 0}, v}], Black, Line[maxr {v, 1.04 v}]}, 
      Text[ToString@a ~~ "\[Degree]", 1.12 maxr v]}], {a, 0, 330, 
     30}], LightGray, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, r], {r, 0, maxr, maxr/4}], 
   Black, Circle[{0, 0}, maxr], 
   Point[RotationTransform[
        VectorAngle[{1, 0}, Most[#]]][{VectorAngle[#, {0, 0, 1}]/
         Degree, 1}]] & /@ 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1/3], {200, 3}]}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Here's one way to use `ListPolarPlot` for point plotting and to apply own custom labelling on it:

```
With[{
  (* angles in degrees, converted to radians later *)

  data = Table[{4 t , t}, {t, 0, 90, 5}],
  rmax = 90,
  rtick = 30,
  atick = 15},
 ListPolarPlot[{Degree, 1} # & /@ data, 
  PlotRange -> 1.2 rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
  Prolog -> {Table[
     With[{v = RotationTransform[a Degree][{rmax, 0}]}, {LightGray, 
       Line[{{0, 0}, v}], Black, Line[{v, 1.04 v}], 
       Text[a Degree, 1.12 v]}], {a, 0, 360 - atick, atick}], 
    Table[{LightGray, Circle[{0, 0}, r], Black, 
      Text[r Degree, {0, -r}, Bottom]}, {r, 0, rmax, rtick}], Black, 
    Circle[{0, 0}, rmax]}]]
```

[image]

It takes a bit of effort to handle degrees-radians conversion but thankfully it's easy on Mma with `Degree`.

Comment: The part of graphics of the circles are easy to understand in the code, thank you, but how’d I put my points in it with a 2 dimension list ? The point part is hard to understand.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a list of two-dimensional coordinates, or something else? In my case I must admit that I created the example set by generating random 3D points and measuring angles from specific vectors to generate angles on the diagram. This can be simplified if you have a specific use case on mind.

Comment: I do have a specific dataset to plot, which consist of two-dimensional coordinates, one is azimuthal angle and the other is zenith angle; and I’d like to plot it with azimuthal angle to rotate and zenith angle as the radius, but I don’t know how...

Comment: @Fabrina I've updated the answer. Does it answer your question?